# How to make a request of request_receipt?

Tags: uber-api

I'm trying to make a request to get receipt but I can't! I have fill all the authorizations section in my Dashboard developer and nothing!

How can I do that?

This is my settings:
[image: screen 1]
[image: screen 2]
[image: screen 3]

I'm trying using chrome Postman
[image: screen 4]

What I need to do? What is missing in the request?
Thank you so much for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

To get "receipt" you will need to use the following endpoint: 
`GET /requests/{request_id}/receipt` where "request_id" is actual ride request id you got when new ride was created. From your history, I don't see any ride request created - so you will always get one empty response.
Before you can use most of the API endpoints you will need to authenticate your user.  For more info on how to do it please check this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45729991/this-endpoint-requires-at-least-one-of-the-following-scopes-all-trips-lite-req).

Comment: Thank you Sasa.
But where I can get the request_id? Or can I use anything like id?

Comment: How can I simulate this ride?

Comment: When you create your ride request you will get  **"request_id"** in the response, check following [documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/sandbox#step-1-create-sandbox-request)

Comment: I can't create the request_id... I follow the example, using postman and I always see the same response:
"{
    "message": "This endpoint requires at least one of the following scopes: request.delegate.tos_accept, request, request.delegate",
    "code": "unauthorized"
}"
And I don't know where and how to put this scopes.

Comment: You will need to investigate and read documentation yourself. You can find more info about your question in following [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45729991/this-endpoint-requires-at-least-one-of-the-following-scopes-all-trips-lite-req/45740848#45740848)

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says

`This endpoint requires at least one of the following scopes: request.delegate.tos_accept, request, request.delegate`

, you will need to include the scopes needed when **requesting** the access token.

To request the access token, you need to authenticate and then following these [steps](https://developer.uber.com/docs/drivers/guides/authentication#step-three-get-an-access-token) with your Developer Account.

Comment: @GustavoSevero Follow Step4 to use the Bearer Token