# Uber Sandbox API Implementing issue ,I am calling sandbox API to book a cab using endpoint https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/requests?

Tags: sandbox, uber-api

My first doubt i don't have full Access 
1) all_trips
2) request_receipt
3) receipt
So, Can I book the rides and test using Sandbox all type of booking and cancel API's
for live booking and cancel we need full acess but for sandbox we need or not ?

I am able to get produts means available cabs using Sandbox API like below :

https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/sandbox/products/

I am able to get estimated prices for available cabs using Sandbox API like below :

https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/estimates/price?start_latitude=12.9279&start_longitude=77.6271&end_latitude=12.9082&end_longitude=77.6074

But ,I stucked here iam unable to book the Cab like below:

URL with parameters :

https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/requests?product_id=ed5e79f0-c124-4377-89eb-511cbdeb5fe2&start_latitude=12.916575700000001&start_longitude=77.6101163&end_latitude=12.9279231856508&end_longitude=77.6271079480648&fare_id=abcd

Headers :
Authorization : [{"key":"Authorization","value":"Bearer KA.eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoyLCJpZCI6Ii9iMFhKalZXVGZXU3JrWWc1YUo0Vmc9PSIsImV4cGlyZXNfYXQiOjE1MjA3NjUwNTQsInBpcGVsaW5lX2tleV9pZCI6Ik1RPT0iLCJwaXBlbGluZV9pZCI6MX0.fq9u5O-DbSixXjAWWpn0W2QrHSJomUBccfXGVx2uw1c","description":""}]

Content-type : application/json

Response is if i use generated service token from dashboard:

{
    "message": "This endpoint requires at least one of the following scopes: request.delegate.tos_accept, request, request.delegate",
    "code": "unauthorized"
}

Response is if i use user authorized  token using authorization url :
Auth URL : https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=&scope=all_trips+delivery+history+history_lite+places+profile+request_receipt+ride_widgets&redirect_uri=

{
    "message": "Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided.",
    "code": "unauthorized"
}

My Doubt :
In Response message it self clearly states that it requires full access
But I am trying with sandbox ,Sandbox also needs Full Access.

Please Clear my doubt ? Help me out

Comment: In order to access sandbox environment you don't need to have full access to the "request" scope. You can use one of the registered users on your developer dashboard : https://developer.uber.com/dashboard/. When you try get your access token - please select "request" scope on your dev dashboard - or add it to the list of scopes when you create your authorization URL. In your Auth URL supply client_id and redirect_url.

Comment: Thnq for yor reply Sasa Jovanovic.

Comment: I followed the below steps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45729991/this-endpoint-requires-at-least-one-of-the-following-scopes-all-trips-lite-req/45740848#45740848

Comment: I have one more doubt I invited developer in dashboard accepted the invitation but still show pending from two days. if once registered what are the next steps how to login as developer to trest sandbox APIS

Comment: Please read again above SO thread. When you generate your authorization URL - open it in "Incognito mode" in the browser and when you navigate to that URL - it will ask you to login with your Uber user (developer account) credentials. This is how you authenticate your specific user with your application. When you get "code" do the next step to exchange the code for access_token. Please read Uber documentation about authentication - this will be my last attempt to help you here: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/authentication/user-access-token

Comment: Yes. I read It .Now sucessfully generated code and token .when i trying to book like below :  https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests?start_latitude=12.903967928747843&start_longitude=77.58600007742643&end_latitude=12.910490950770706&end_longitude=77.58571676909924&product_id=3eb15796-edd3-4297-80f1-02605442bb9e7&fare_id=abcd                                                                               response is coming as :  {
    "message": "Unable to parse JSON in request body.",
    "code": "invalid_json"
}      what is solution .Thanks for your helping ? Please be patient and help me

Comment: How do you create your ride request? Can you update your question with the code how you are doing it - so we can help you.